# Return error when try to remove or add a new sublist line

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need help to be able to turn `SALES_ORDER` into `INVOICE` but the sublist item has to be removed and add other value.

> Error message : item_machine is not defined

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Its always good to provide as much context as possible. For example here you are not specifying a  technology, programming language of any relevant information to support your question. See here  See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help

Answer (score 0):

Based on two tags "NetSuite" and "SuiteScript 2.0" assigned to this question, I am trying to answer.

Below line of code is the ready example on SuiteScript2.0 documentation (freely available on web).

This transforms "Sales_Order" into "ItemFulFillMent Record" so, you need to make necessary changes in below code.

```
var fulfillmentRecord = record.transform({
    fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    fromId: salesOrderId, 
    toType: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,
    isDynamic: false
});
var lineCount = fulfillmentRecord.getLineCount('item');
for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    fulfillmentRecord.setSublistValue('item', 'location', i, 1);
// here you can remove, add or modify item lines on ItemFulfillment.
}
var fulfillmentId = fulfillmentRecord.save();
```